# What is the difference between setq and set-variable in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

What is the difference between setq and set-variable in emacs lisp. When should I use setq and when should I set-variable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`set-variable` is an interactive command, meaning that you can type <kbd>M-x set-variable RET</kbd> to be interactively prompted for a variable name and value.  `setq` is not an interactive command, meaning it's only suitable for writing in Emacs Lisp code.  Personally, I never use `set-variable` in my Lisp code, only interactively, when I want to give a value to a variable that has an immediate effect on my text editing, such as (for example) setting `indent-tabs-mode` to `t` or `nil`.

Another difference is that `setq` can set multiple variables at once.  For example, in my .emacs file on OS X I have:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta
      mac-option-modifier 'super)
```

`set-variable` can't do that.

Answer (score 12):

`setq` is a [special form](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Forms.html), while `set-variable` is an interactive function.

From [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/defvar-and-asterisk.html):

> For me, the major use of the
>   `set-variable` command is to suggest
>   variables that I might want to set in
>   my `.emacs` file.  There are now more
>   than 700 such variables -- far too
>   many to remember readily. Fortunately,
>   you can press `<TAB>` after calling the
>   `M-x set-variable` command to see the
>   list of variables.

Answer (score 4):

Besides what was said above, for `set-variable`, as the doc string says:

```
    VARIABLE should be a user option variable name, a Lisp variable
    meant to be customized by users.
```

`setq` applies to any variable, whether or not it is a user option.

Comment: Yes, but there doesn't seem to be any enforcement of this, which is too bad.

Comment: You cannot use it interactively on a non-option variable - no match.